# Can a shared interrupt line in Linux have different interrupt handlers?

Tags: c, linux, interrupt-handling

Can an interrupt line shared by different drivers have different unique interrupt handlers? For example, would something like this be possible?

on driver1 : `request_irq(irq, &handler1, IRQF_SHARED,"dev1", dev1);`

on driver2 : `request_irq(irq, &handler2, IRQF_SHARED,"dev2", dev2);`

Comment: Clarify title, improve language

Comment: Clarify title, improve grammar

Comment: Related question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47306/how-does-the-linux-kernel-handle-shared-irqs can help you

Answer (score 0):

If **all** drivers that want to share this IRQ are requesting it with `IRQF_SHARED` this works - If only one of them does **not** set that flag, i.e. wants the IRQ exclusively, your `request_irq` will fail.

Another precondition is that your handler needs to be able to recognise somehow from the hardware whether it was *his* device that triggered the IRQ or not. This determines the return value of the handler.

The kernel will call all handlers that share the IRQ in sequence until it found one that actually handled it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @tofro